# Video not showing Drupal

Tags: drupal, html5-video

I am having an issue displaying a video with Drupal.

Here is the test page: http://audi.edelmandigital.com.au/post/test-video

I use Mediabrowser to select a thumbnail then Edit and add the video file.

I get the thumbnail and when I click on it, the audio plays but the video is not showing.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it's css issue I have add  the below code in firebug and video is showing

```
.media .fill-area {
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]